# N-tier web API application with autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity

I develop aspnet webapi app using dependency injection with Autofac and i've got one trouble.

I created model **Order**, repository for it and **Unit of Work**.

```
public class Order
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime CompletedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

**OrderRepository.cs**

```
public class OrderRepository : IRepository<Order>
    {
        private ApplicationContext database;

        public OrderRepository(ApplicationContext database)
        {
            this.database = database;
        }

        public void Create(Order item)
        {
            database.Orders.Add(item);
        }

        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var order = database.Orders.Find(id);
            if (order != null)
            {
                database.Orders.Remove(order);
            }
        }

        public Order Get(int id)
        {
            return database.Orders.Find(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Order> GetList()
        {
            return database.Orders;
        }

        public void Update(Order item)
        {
            database.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private ApplicationContext database;
        private OrderRepository orderRepository;

        private bool disposed = false;

        public IRepository<Order> Orders
        {
            get
            {
                if (orderRepository == null)
                {
                    orderRepository = new OrderRepository(database);
                }

                return orderRepository;
            }
        }

        public UnitOfWork(ApplicationContext database)
        {
            this.database = database;
        }

        public async Task SaveAsync()
        {
            await database.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    database.Dispose();
                }
                this.disposed = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

Then i made **OrderManager**

```
public class OrderManager : IOrderManager
    {
        IUnitOfWork database;

        public OrderManager(IUnitOfWork database)
        {
            this.database = database;
        }

        public void CreateOrder(OrderViewModel order)
        {
            database.Orders.Create(new Order
            {
                UserId = order.UserId,
                Header = order.Header,
                Description = order.Description,
                City = order.City,
                Address = order.Address,
                Price = order.Price,
                Name = order.Name,
                PhoneNumber = order.PhoneNumber,
                CompletedOn = order.CompletedOn,
                CreatedAt = order.CreatedAt,
                UpdatedAt = order.UpdatedAt
            });
        }

        public Order GetOrder(int id)
        {
            return database.Orders.Get(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders()
        {
            return database.Orders.GetList();
        }
    }
```

Then i tried to make **inject** and i think somewhere here error because i writing this.

```
public static void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(User).Assembly);

            builder.RegisterType<ApplicationContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest().WithParameter("connectionString", "DefaultConnection");
            builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.Register(c => new UnitOfWork(c.Resolve<ApplicationContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<OrderManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
            //builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().WithParameter("database", new ApplicationContext("DefaultConnection")); ;
            builder.RegisterType<UserStore<User>>().As<IUserStore<User>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.Register(c => new UserStore<User>(c.Resolve<ApplicationContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<RoleStore<IdentityRole>>().As<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            //builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).As<IAuthenticationManager>();

            builder.Register(c => new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>
            {
                DataProtectionProvider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider("ASP.NET Identity​")
            });

            var container = builder.Build();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        }
```

And the place where error pops up

```
 protected OrderManager orderManager;

        public ValuesController()
        { }

        public ValuesController(OrderManager orderManager)
        {
            this.orderManager = orderManager;
        }

        public OrderManager OrderManager
        {
            get
            {
                return orderManager;
            }
            set
            {
                orderManager = value;
            }
        }

public OrderViewModel Get(int id)
        {
            var order = OrderManager.GetOrder(id);

            var orderViewModel = new OrderViewModel
            {
                Header = order.Header,
                Description = order.Description,
            };

            return orderViewModel;
        }
```

When i getting order the site drop because OrderManager is null. I suppose problem in the my DI realization but i still don't know how to fix it.

[image: Error]

Comment: what is the exception message? can share it your question

Comment: @Vinit in the end of question.

Comment: you have two constructors, can you debug and see which constructor is getting called for ValuesController.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); you posted [too much code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/). And [don't post images of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) and [add exception details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your setup code is not correct. In the ConfigureCOntainer, do this

```
 public static void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Get your HttpConfiguration.
            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            // Register your Web API controllers.
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
            builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

            // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac model binder provider.
            builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();


            builder.RegisterType<ApplicationContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest().WithParameter("connectionString", "DefaultConnectionString");
            builder.Register(c => new UnitOfWork(c.Resolve<ApplicationContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<OrderManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();



            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
            var container = builder.Build();
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }
```

and that method should be called before other API config code like

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            ConfigureContainer();

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


        }


        public static void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Get your HttpConfiguration.
            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            // Register your Web API controllers.
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
            builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

            // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac model binder provider.
            builder.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();


            builder.RegisterType<ApplicationContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest().WithParameter("connectionString", "DefaultConnectionString");
            builder.Register(c => new UnitOfWork(c.Resolve<ApplicationContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<OrderManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();



            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
            var container = builder.Build();
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
```

I can see the instance is created correctly in Web Api controller

[image]

The controller code is

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public ValuesController(OrderManager orderManager)
        {
            this.OrderManager = orderManager;
        }

        public OrderManager OrderManager { get; set; }


        [Route("orders")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
        {
            return Ok("Received");
        }

        [Route("orders/{id}")]
        public OrderViewModel Get(int id)
        {
            var order = OrderManager.GetOrder(id);

            var orderViewModel = new OrderViewModel
            {
                Header = order.Header,
                Description = order.Description,
            };

            return orderViewModel;
        }
```

Comment: If i do it then there will be an error "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ValuesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

Comment: I think it can help, but after trying your code occurs new error System.NullReferenceException Owin.<>c__2`1.<CreatePerOwinContext>b__2_0(IdentityFactoryOptions`1 options, T instance) +6

Probably this method break old dependencies with User and ApplicationUserManager

Comment: thank you for your help so much. I solve problem with your code. I've got the IoC in side project and when i put builder in webapiconfig it works. Unfortunately, now occured error with ApplicationUserManager, but this problem another sense. Thank you again